# My autoload function doesnt work but it seems the class is loaded PHP

Tags: php, html, css, web, autoload

I'm a new PHP deveploper and I'm having a bad time with the autoload function.  This is the error.

```
public class dog{ public function hey($var){ echo $var; } }
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'dog' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ebay\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ebay\index.php on line 3
```

It shows the class but then echo a error.

This is the autoload function.

```
require_once("config.php");
spl_autoload_register("my_auto_load");

function my_auto_load($class_name){
    $path = "classes";
    require_once($path.DS.$class_name.".php");
}
```

And this is the index file

```
require_once("config.php");
spl_autoload_register("my_auto_load");

function my_auto_load($class_name){
    $path = "classes";
    require_once($path.DS.$class_name.".php");
}
```

And this is the index file

```
<?php 
require_once("inc/autoload.php");
$dog= new dog();
$dog->hey("KLK");
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you could do to track down your problem.  Try updating your autoload function to look like this:

```
function my_auto_load($class_name){
  $path = "classes";

  $includeFilename = $path.DS.$class_name.".php";

  ?>
  Class: <?= $class_name; ?><br>
  Include Filename: <?= $includeFilename; ?><br>
  Include Filename Real Path: <?= realpath($includeFilename); ?><br>
  Current working directory: <?= getcwd(); ?><br>
  Does the include file exists? <?= file_exists($includeFilename) ? "Yes, it exists" : "No, it doesn't exist"; ?><br>
  <?php

  require_once($includeFilename);
}
```

This will show you whether your autoload function is even running, and if it is running, what file it's actually trying to include and whether that file exists.  If it's creating the filepath correctly and the file exists, then your problem is likely somewhere else.

I re-created your project and it seems to work fine.  This is my directory structure:

```
./classes/dog.php
./inc/autoload.php
./index.php
```

### `index.php`

```
<?php

require_once("inc/autoload.php");
$dog= new dog();
$dog->hey("KLK");
```

### `inc/autoload.php`

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register("my_auto_load");
function my_auto_load($class_name){
    $path = "classes";

    $includeFilename = $path.'/'.$class_name.".php";

?>
  Class: <?= $class_name; ?><br>
  Include Filename: <?= $includeFilename; ?><br>
  Include Filename Real Path: <?= realpath($includeFilename); ?><br>
  Current working directory: <?= getcwd(); ?><br>
  Does the include file exists? <?= file_exists($includeFilename) ? "Yes, it exists" : "No, it doesn't exist"; ?><br>
<?php

    require_once($includeFilename);
}
```

### `classes/dog.php`

```
<?php

class dog {
    public function hey($msg) {
        echo $msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it doesnt print the class anymore just give me this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'dog' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ebay\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ebay\index.php on line 3

Comment: You could try adding something like `if($class_name == 'dog') die();` right before the require_once.  Then you'll at least see the summary printed.

Comment: Try putting `var_dump($class_name); die();` at the beginning of your my_auto_load function.

Comment: Try replacing the `DS` constant with the string `'/'`.  E.g. `$includeFilename = $path.'/'.$class_name.".php";`

Comment: This is how I declared the constant defined("DS") || define("DS",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

Comment: I think there someting wrong with my server then because it is the same.

Comment: Keep putting something like `die('here');` in your code, and moving it further along until the program doesn't die with that message.  It might help you narrow down where the problem is.